# New project fails using WebAPI and Breeze

Tags: breeze

I receive the following error when trying to run the new project per the instruction in the Readme file.

1: querying Todos

2: Query failed: The action 'Todos' on controller 'BreezeSample' with return type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[MyTasks.Api.Models.BreezeSampleTodoItem, MyTasks.Api, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' cannot support querying. Ensure the type of the returned content is IEnumerable, IQueryable, or a generic form of either interface.

UPDATE:

I checked my event viewer, and see a SQL error that I've never seen before when trying to debug on my machine -

Login failed for user 'my-machine\user-name'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database. [CLIENT: ]

It seems that the database being generated by BreezeSamplesContext is inaccessible for some reason?  It has been generated by code-first, but I can't query it (apparently).

UPDATE 2:

I've changed the default method to -

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<BreezeSampleTodoItem> Todos()
{
    System.Data.Entity.DbSet<BreezeSampleTodoItem> result = null;
    try
    {
        result = _contextProvider.Context.Todos;
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        throw new Exception(exc.Message);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Although the Seed method works, and the database is dropped and repopulated with seed values, I get a response of 0 items in the 'result' above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE: December 15**

The critical piece of information ... the reason for the problem ... is the use of the **pre-release SPA template**.

That template is not the same as the MVC 4 **Web API** or **Empty** templates that are described in the Breeze documentation

The **SPA Template** and the MVC update include the beginnings of ASP.NET Web API support for OData queries. Their stab at OData conflicts with Breeze; the two forces are wrestling for ownership of the OData query. Wish we could use theirs but it is missing essential features such as support for $select and $expand.

Fortunately, it is easy to disable the MS version so that Breeze prevails. Open **App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs** file and **delete or comment out** the following:

```
config.EnableQuerySupport(); // conflicts with Breeze's ODataActionFilter
```

The misleading error about "return type" should disappear and you should be back in business.

Note that taking this step turns off the MS Web API OData filter for the entire site. We have it on our backlog to update the Breeze `ODataActionFilterAttribute` so that it disables the MS Web API OData handling *for the Breeze controller only*. We hadn't bothered yet because the SPA template remains unofficial at this time. For the nonce ... you can't mix Breeze and Web API OData queries in the same site ... unless you're prepared to do the per-controller filter cleanup yourself.

We have a Breeze version of the new SPA Template working and almost ready to release. I'll be writing about it shortly and will update this answer with a link.

Below is my previous answer which I preserve mostly because (a) it describes how to diagnose a problem and (b) is the context for the comment chain.

---

Let's start over and see if we can diagnose. Close all Visual Studio sessions (that should stop IIS Express). Launch a fresh VS session. Create an MVC4 Web Api application in VS 2012. Add the *Breeze.MVC4WebApiClientSample* NuGet package. Run it (F5). Still having trouble?

If so, let's update the controller method with a new line like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable Todos() {
    var items = _contextProvider.Context.Todos.ToList(); // test the query
    return _contextProvider.Context.Todos;
}
```

Put a breakpoint on the `var items ...` line and re-run with the debugger (F5). Step into that line. Did it throw (not good but interesting)? If not, how many items did you get? Zero? You should have 6.

If you can't get past this point, I don't think this is a Breeze problem. Breeze hasn't done anything yet. I'd be looking for something unexpected in your environment.

Let us know how it stands when you get to this point; if still stuck we'll be ready for next steps.

Comment: Yes, I get six items back using this code.  Of course, I still get an error, especially now that we're converting to a List.  Taking it one step further, I converted the return type to IQueryable, using AsQueryable(), but still get the same error.

Comment: One extra piece of info.  When I try to evaluate the return type of '_contextProvider.Context.Todos' during debugging - using the initial code, not the piece you sent - I get an interesting response.  It appears as though the calls are timing out right away, even though I'm evaluating the calls immediately after invoking the debugger.

I get the following error: Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation.

Comment: Also, interestingly enough, if I use the following code, and set a break point at itemList...

`var items = _contextProvider.Context.Todos;
var itemList = items.ToList();
return items;`

....I get this error:

_Cannot drop database "BreezeSampleContext-20121213144159" because it is currently in use._

Comment: NOTE:  In comment above, I do not have the database open in any tools.  It is as though the ContextProvider is locking the database.  The code passes through line 1 just fine, but when I try to convert items.ToList(), I get the database error.

Comment: This thread establishes that something is going on having to do with your EF and db environments and nothing obviously to do with Breeze. The "context" you get is a raw EF DbContext. You can verify that by spinning up your own instance of a DbContext and trying to make it work. Forget about returning anything; just try to fetch the Todos a few times. I can try to run it on my machine if you like: email it to me at breeze at ideablade dot com

Comment: The only thing that makes me question that conclusion is that every app involving API or MVC works great including EF.  Including the very latest 2012.2 release of Web Tools and the SPA template.  Only when I install Breeze does anything break.  All this makes me conclude is that Breeze is at fault.  I would like to work with you on discovering the real culprit, so let's see if the source I send you can assist.

Comment: Good news is that your submission fails on my machine too. So I have something to dig into.

Comment: Perhaps you didn't quite tell me everything :)  The project you sent has DotNetOpenAuth in it, login and registration views, WebMatrix dlls, and who knows what else. How did that stuff get in there? You're missing the System.Web.Providers dll. I'll send you a zip that works. Maybe we need to keep this on email.

Comment: Thank you.  For anyone else running into trouble, this was the default build using VS 2012 and Web Tools 2012.2.  I did a fresh install of MVC 4 using the SPA template, and then installed Breeze (so just SPA and Breeze).  The code I sent to you is the culmination of those default installs - nothing more.  So, this thread may come in useful to others :)

Comment: NOTE:  Above was using Web Tools 2012.2 Release Candidate (RC)

Comment: Ah ... the **SPA Template**. Wish I'd known that. I see it now in our comment exchange but missed it as I was concentrating on the documented path through the Web API and Empty templates. I've updated my answer to show the way forward.

Answer (score 0):

The sample from NuGet is set up to drop and re-create the database every time you run the code. Do you happen to have the database open in a SQL Management Studio? I ran into this as well.

Take a look at the BreezeSampleDatabaseInitializer class. Check out the comment that talks about preserving the changes between server sessions. If you change the class to implement the DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges interface it will only try to drop the database when you change the model.

Comment: The database is dropping and regenerating as expected, and the seed data is being populated. However, when I run the app, I get the above error.  I was able to configure the app to use both SQL Express and an MDF file, and both ended in the same result. In SQL express I received the Login Failed message. I don't receive any SQL related errors with the MDF. The strangest part is that the return type is IQueryable<BreezeSampleTodoItem>, yet the app throws an error complaining of a return type of List. This makes no sense to me. Nowhere am I returning a collection of type List.

Comment: This may not be of much help, but I am seeing the same events being logged on my dev box. Did you change the BreezeSample Controller from the "out of the box"? If so can you post the Todos action code? I am betting that you have not, but its worth a shot to ask.

Comment: I didn't...except for the Update noted above.  I wanted to capture any exceptions and the return value from the ContextProvider.  The response is not an exception, but the return count is 0.